# Yii: Getting the role of logged in users and showing content according to role

Tags: php, yii

I want to get the roles of the registered users and show the content to the registered users according to their roles. 
I have two users right now.

1. admin
2. user(authenticated)

The thing i am trying to do is that when the admin logs in via "**webapp/user/login**" a sidebarwidget which i have already made should be shown upon login and when the user(authenticated) gets logged in, the user(authenticated) should only be able to see the index.php page.

I am using **Yii users** and **rights**. I have looked around and found this piece of code which is for getting the role of the logged in user but I dont know where to place this piece of code to get the output. 
Below are two pieces of codes, please do tell me which one will be more useful.

```
 if($user = Users::model()->findAll()) {
    foreach($user as $id => $user) {
    if(!$user->checkAccess('Authenticated')) {
        unset($user[$id]);
        }
    }
    $users = array_values($user); // to reset indices (optional)
}
```

and this is another piece of code which i have found.

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `authassignment` WHERE userid={$user->id}");
$results = $command->queryAll();
$roles = array();
foreach ($results as $result)
{
  $roles[] = $result['itemname'];
}
$this->setState('roles', $roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have done following tutorials, here is a proposal.

The authentication can take place in file protected/components/UserIdentity.php :

```
public function authenticate($native=false){
    $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
    //can provide function "same" if needed - found it here:
    //http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13512
    if($record!==null&&$this->same($record->password,crypt($this->password,$record->password)){
        $authRoleName=Role::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$record->role_id))->name;
        $this->setState('role_name', $authRoleName);
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
    }else{
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_UNKNOWN_IDENTITY;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

In this case the several roles (admin, mobile, user, etc) are stored in db (table roles) and each user model has a role_id.

I assume the SiteController does the login (file protected/controllers/SiteController.php):

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login()){
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
        }
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

File protected/models/LoginForm.php:

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
public $username;
public $password;
public $rememberMe;

private $_identity;

public function authenticate($attribute,$params)
{
    if(!$this->hasErrors())
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        if(!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            $this->addError('password','False username or password.');
    }
}

public function login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity, duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

In view you could do a role based decision making, like the example below in file protected/views/site/index.php :

```
<?php
$userModel =User::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId()));
if($userModel){
    if(Yii::app()->user->getState('role_name') == 'admin'){
        $this->renderPartial(
        //...
        );
     }else{
         //...
     }
}
```

Moreover, if RBAC is on your mind, and you manage to have a proper protected/data/auth.php (there are ways for this, I use command "./protected/yiic rbac" after creating file protected/commands/RbacCommand.php - I can post this latter file if needed) then in any place in your code you simply:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('admin')){
    //staff for admins
}
```

Also, in this case, you could set the rights of whole actions in controller's  function accessRules() by issuing roles instead of usernames:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array{
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('index', 'index2', 'view','create','update','getRecordDetails', 'getTotalCount'),
            'roles'=>array('admin'),
        ),
    );
}
```